# How to remove sequential matches in vector in Clojure?

Tags: algorithm, vector, clojure

Let's say I have a vector `["a" "b" "c" "a" "a" "b"]`. If given a sequence `["a" "b"]`, how can I remove all instances of that sequence (in order)? Here, the result would just be `["c" "a"]`.

Answer (score 6):

If sequences that need to be removed are known in advance, `core.match` may be useful for your task:

```
(require '[clojure.core.match :refer [match]])

(defn remove-patterns [seq]
  (match seq
    ["a" "b" & xs] (remove-patterns xs)
    [x & xs] (cons x (remove-patterns xs))
    [] ()))


(remove-patterns ["a" "b" "c" "a" "a" "b"]) ;; => ("c" "a")
```

Comment: The usual reminder for recursive solutions, there’s a danger of blowing the stack when the collection is large …

Answer (score 5):

The short answer is to treat it as a string and do a regex remove:

```
(defn remove-ab [v]
  (mapv str (clojure.string/replace (apply str v) #"ab" "")))

(remove-ab ["a" "b" "c" "a" "a" "b"])
=> ["c" "a"]
```

The long answer is to implement your own regex state machine by iterating through the sequence, identifying matches, and returning a sequence without them.

Automat can help with making your own low level regex state machine:
https://github.com/ztellman/automat

Instaparse can be used to make rich grammas:
https://github.com/Engelberg/instaparse

You don't really need a library for such a small match, you can implement it as a loop:

```
(defn remove-ab [v]
  (loop [[c & remaining] v
         acc []
         saw-a false]
    (cond
     (nil? c) (if saw-a (conj acc "a") acc) ;; terminate
     (and (= "b" c) saw-a) (recur remaining acc false)  ;; ignore ab
     (= "a" c) (recur remaining (if saw-a (conj acc "a") acc) true) ;; got a
     (and (not= "b" c) saw-a) (recur remaining (conj (conj acc "a") c) false) ;; keep ac
     :else (recur remaining (conj acc c) false)))) ;; add c
```

But getting all the conditions right can be tricky... hence why a formal regex or state machine is advantageous.

Or a recursive definition:

```
(defn remove-ab [[x y & rest]]
  (cond
   (and (= x "a") (= y "b")) (recur rest)
   (nil? x) ()
   (nil? y) [x]
   :else (cons x (remove-ab (cons y rest)))))
```

Comment: Thanks, probably should have mentioned this is actually what I'm currently doing but I wasn't sure if there's something more performant that keeps everything as collections. Autoformat looks good though for making an fsm, thanks!

Comment: You can implement it using just `lazy-seq`, `take` and `drop` - please, see my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Recursive solution for a 2-element subsequence:

```
(defn f [sq [a b]]
  (when (seq sq)
    (if 
      (and
        (= (first sq) a)
        (= (second sq) b))
      (f (rest (rest sq)) [a b]) 
      (cons (first sq) (f (rest sq) [a b])))))
```

not exhaustively tested but seems to work.

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution using `lazy-seq`, `take` and `drop` working for any finite subseq and any (including infinite) sequence that needs to be filtered:

```
(defn remove-subseq-at-start
  [subseq xs]
  (loop [xs xs]
    (if (= (seq subseq) (take (count subseq) xs))
      (recur (drop (count subseq) xs))
      xs)))

(defn remove-subseq-all [subseq xs]
  (if-let [xs (seq (remove-subseq-at-start subseq xs))]
    (lazy-seq (cons (first xs) (remove-subseq subseq (rest xs))))
    ()))

(deftest remove-subseq-all-test
  (is (= ["c" "a"] (remove-subseq-all ["a" "b"] ["a" "b" "a" "b" "c" "a" "a" "b"])))
  (is (= ["a"] (remove-subseq-all ["a" "b"] ["a"])))
  (is (= ["a" "b"] (remove-subseq-all [] ["a" "b"])))
  (is (= [] (remove-subseq-all ["a" "b"] ["a" "b" "a" "b"])))
  (is (= [] (remove-subseq-all ["a" "b"] nil)))
  (is (= [] (remove-subseq-all [] [])))
  (is (= ["a" "b" "a" "b"] (->> (remove-subseq-all ["c" "d"] (cycle ["a" "b" "c" "d"]))
                                (drop 2000000)
                                (take 4))))

  (is (= (seq "ca") (remove-subseq-all "ab" "ababcaab"))))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can ensure that the input is a vector, we can use `subvec` to check on every element whether the following subvector of the same length matches the pattern. If so, we omit it, otherwise we move ahead to the next element in the vector:

```
(let [pattern ["a" "b"]
      source ["a" "b" "c" "a" "a" "b"]]
    (loop [source source
           pattern-length (count pattern)
           result []]
        (if (< (count source) pattern-length)
            (into [] (concat result source))
            (if (= pattern (subvec source 0 pattern-length))
              ; skip matched part of source
              (recur (subvec source pattern-length) pattern-length result)
              ; otherwise move ahead one element and save it as result
              (recur (subvec source 1) pattern-length 
                     (conj result (first source)))))))
```

With general sequences, you could use the same approach, substituting `take` and `drop` as appropriate.